# Sending Output to stdout and send output to a definition

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, stdout, stopwatch

I'm trying to create a stopwatch, define it and output to a script and stdout all the results to a file.

I already have a script that reports CPU, RX, TX, MB and interrupts, I just need
seconds during a 15 minute run like below example

```
CPU   RXPKTS  TXPKTS   MB/READ MB/WRITE INTERRUPTS  STOPWATCH 

98    928373  282675   521M    120M     282725.34   00.10 
98   10008373 282435   921M    420M     182725.34   01.00
98   10008373 282435   921M    420M     182725.34   03.10
```

Script should complete with time and seconds like below example:

```
                                                  stopwatch
98   10008373 282435   921M    420M     182725.34   07.34
```

I currently have the below:

```
date1=`date +%s`; while true; do
   echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%M:%S)\r" ;
done
```

The script doesn't output a single line. I would like to define it instead to a variable like this:

```
printf '%20s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s\n' "$edate" $HOSTNAME $cpustat $eth $hhd $itr **$stopwatch**
```

I would like to only use bash.

Comment: I don't understand the question here. What are you trying to do that you are having trouble doing?

Comment: To simply report time from start to finish in a script. I don't want a date and time but in minutes and seconds starting @ 00.00 until end of a hadoop terasort like I explained above.  Example above.